# Android: OpenGL: glGenTextures not working in constructor?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, sdk

Can anyone tell me why `glGenTextures()` isn't working in my constructor?

Here is how my project is setup:

- A custom renderer is used which calls `.draw` on the current active stage.
- When a stage is created it assigns itself (the end line of its constructor) to the static `Global.activeStage`.
- Now the renderer calls `.draw` on the currently active stage which reference is kept inside `Global.activeStage`.
- In the stage I have a function which loads all textures that are needed in the stage.
- If I call this function the first time `.draw` is called there is no problem.
- If I call it in the constructor though, everything works except `glGenTextures()` - it creates a zero value rather than 1..2..3 and so on.
- In both cases a global `GL10` reference is used rather than the one `.draw` gets, so it's not the problem.

It seems as if everything works ONLY if there is already a reference to the current stage I'm using (if the stage is created e.g. the constructor has already run).

I am not sure if it is related, but the stage is created in a Thread after `onCreateSurface` ends.

I could post some of the code if you say which parts would be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I am quite sure you have to run all `openGL` operations on the `Thread` associated with `openGL`. This is why it works when called from your `draw()` method called from the renderer (which runs on the GL-Thread) but not from the constructor (which runs on another Thread as you say).

Comment: Makes sence, but breaks my entire idea.. Is there a way I could pass the GL thread context to a function called inside the Stage thread, say right after I call the constructor? I really need to do all the texture work inside a thread independent of the renderer's call to `.draw()`. The final goal is to `draw()` a 'loading' image while loading all textures and stuff for the new stage. That's why I need it in a thread, otherwise it just freezes until all the work is done.

Comment: The easiest way is if you have a `GLSurfaceView` that you render in, then you can just call its `queueEvent()`-method with a `Runnable`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#queueEvent%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: Actually it does not work, adding it to the GL thread just makes it hang while working. It is equivalent to adding the code right there without any thread, waits to finish executing before the next `.draw()`..

Comment: @Tony well, obviously. You should run as much of your loading as possible on separate threads, and then just do the final work on your ui / gl Threads (such as generating textures)

Comment: That's the point, my loading is actually loading textures and binding them in GL, how can I load textures outside GL!? I have no heavy initialising except the textures..

Comment: You either load your textures using a call to `BitmapFactory` or by using the `ETC1Util` depending on texture type. Do this first on a separate thread, and then only do the binding on the GL-Thread.